# How to install a "not found" function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function

I am using Matlab R2010a on Windows 7 64 bit.

When I was using `imfindcircles`, I got the error.

```
>> [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(image,[100 400],'ObjectPolarity','dark')
??? Undefined function or method 'imfindcircles' for input arguments of type
'uint8'.
```

I referenced [a helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197441/matlab-error-undefined-function-or-method-x-for-input-arguments-of-type-double) and found out that I cannot find `imfindcircles` function.

```
>> which imfindcircles
'imfindcircles' not found.
>> help imfindcircles

imfindcircles not found.

Use the Help browser Search tab to search the documentation, or
type "help help" for help command options, such as help for methods.
```

I cannot find imfindcircles.m on my computer.

**EDIT**:

I checked the functions in the [MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/functionlist.html), and found `imread`.

```
>> which imread
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\imread.m
```

I found some function in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\matlab\imagesci and C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\images, but I don't have imfindcircles.m. Should I download imfindcircles.m somewhere and put it into an directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have toolbox ver. 8.0 or greater to find imfindcircles. use "ver" to find the installed version for image processing toolbox

Comment: Thanks! My Image Processing Toolbox is 7.0. The only solution is to use newer Matlab?

Comment: I also want to know how to find out that I need toolbox ver. 8.0 or greater to find imfindcircles, I can't find the information on the website. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

[`imfindcircles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) is part of the [Image Processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/).
You need to have this toolbox and to have a valid license for it.

Did you check if you have any of the other functions in this toolbox?

Comment: Yeah I can find some of the functions in Image Processing Toolbox. But there is no imfindcircles, I edited my question.