# Undefined function 'mat2vec' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I have already read the [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197441/matlab-error-undefined-function-or-method-x-for-input-arguments-of-type-double)

I do not understand the answer in the other thread, what is it I am supposed to be doing.

Comment: What is `mat2vec` in your case? A function you have defined?

Comment: @Nemesis ah no! It's supposed to transform a matrix into a vector! Is it not a standard matlab function? That would explain it all.

Comment: Right, it is not shipped with Matlab. However, maybe it is [this file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29876-linstats/content/LinStats2011/mat2vec.m).

Comment: @Nemesis in any case you have answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

For any ND matrix in Matlab, you can simply list values from 1 to end:

```
>> a = rand(2)

a =

    0.3404    0.2238
    0.5853    0.7513

>> a(1:end)

ans =

    0.3404    0.5853    0.2238    0.7513
```

If you were looking for row-by-row, then you can transpose first:

```
>> b = a'

b =

    0.3404    0.5853
    0.2238    0.7513

>> b(1:end)

ans =

    0.3404    0.2238    0.5853    0.7513
```