# Digital signature mulino function

Tags: matlab

Hi i am trying to run implentation of digital signture, i get an error:
**"Undefined function 'mulinv' for input arguments of type 'double'."**
I insert the number 9 and 23 as constant in purpose, because the error is about the variables type.

My code is:

```
addpath('C:\MATLAB\R2015a\VariablePrecisionIntegers');
disp('Implementation of ELGAMAL Digital Signature');
addpath('search-ms:query=mulinv\mulinv');
addpath('');
clear all; 
close all;

%%Hardcoded values (vpi stands for VariablePrecisionIntegers, and are used to store large values)
g = vpi(5)  %alpha in example
k = vpi(9)  %Random number 1<k<p-1 and gcd(k, p ? 1) = 1.
p = vpi(23) %Prime Number
x = vpi(3)  %Secret Key 1 < x < p ? 1
m = vpi(7)  %Message

y = vpi(2)
r = vpi(2)
s = vpi(2)

%%Key Generation
y = powermod(g,x,p)     %y = g^x mod p  

%%Signature Generation
r = powermod(g,k,p)     %r = g^k mod p

multinver = mulinv(9,23)    %Generates multiplicative inverse k^-1 mod p

s = mod(((multinver)*(m-x*r)),p-1)      %s = (k^-1)*(m-x*r) mod p-1


%%Verification
zvg = vpi(2);
zvg = powermod (g,m,p)      %zvg = g^m mod p

zvyr = vpi(2);
zvyr = mod(((y^r)*(r^s)),p) %zvyr = y^r * r^s mod p
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB error: Undefined function or method X for input arguments of type 'double'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197441/matlab-error-undefined-function-or-method-x-for-input-arguments-of-type-double)

Answer (score 1):

Do not `clear all`, just `clear`.

If you `clear all` you also clear all the added paths, therefore making Matlab forget about `addpath('search-ms:query=mulinv\mulinv');`

Read more at: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html